# Select box shrinks in IE7 but not IE6 or IE8

Tags: jquery, select

I'm having a problem in IE7 with jquery and select boxes. When I set the width of a select box and then use jquery to re-populate the items on change of the first select box, the second select box is being reduced based off of the set width.

For example :
The follow code uses two select boxes. When the first select box has a change event triggered, it will remove all the second select box and add some new values. If I remove the style attribute for the second select box the desired behavior is met. With the style attribute left in, the second select box will get smaller and smaller and eventually just disappear.

This only happens in IE7.

Code is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#selOne").change(function(){
                //Clear out the current service list
                $("#selTwo option").each(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
                     var newOption = '<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>';
                     $("#selTwo").append(newOption);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <select id="selOne" class="number req" style="width: 90%;">
         <option value="" selected="selected">Initial Select</option>
         <option value="">a</option>
         <option value="">b</option>
         <option value="">c</option>

    </select>
    <select id="selTwo" class="number req" style="width: 90%;">
         <option value="" selected="selected">These should update</option>
         <option value="">100</option>
         <option value="">101</option>
         <option value="">102</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I still specify a width, but not have the select box shrink down to nothing? Is the only way an absolute width in pixels?

Comment: Looks like a browser bug, not sure what your question is or even if there is one. Looks like you have a perfectly acceptable answer, i.e. use the width style to force the size of the dropdown.

Comment: Lazarus, a browser bug is what I'm afraid of. We have had a hell of a time getting our users off IE6 due to bugs and compatibility issues. Although this is not critical to the user experience, it is an annoyance. Anyways, I added my question at the end of the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code gets the second select box to stay the correct size:

```
        $("#selOne").change(function(){
            //Clear out the current service list
            $("#selTwo option").each(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });

            /* IE7 Fix: reset the width based on pixels
                It doesn't matter to how many, just that
                the width is in pixels
            */
            $("#selTwo").css("width","1px");

            for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
                 var newOption = '<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>';
                 $("#selTwo").append(newOption);
            }

            /*IE7 FIX: rest the width back to our desired percent */
            $("#selTwo").css("width","90%");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
$("<option>").attr("value", i).text(i).appendTo("#selTwo");
```

Comment: This works in getting the option appended to the select box, but the problem of the select box shrinking still remains. I found a work around and have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just used CSS hack for IE7 like following -

```
select.number { *width: 280px !important; }
```

Note: Please change to your equivalent width in px.